# Что такое виртуальный процессор?

Tags: терминология, железо, виртуальная-машина, процессор

1. Где то утверждают что это по сути и есть ядро (или поток ядра). И например при технологии Hyper-Threading система определяет физическое ядро как два виртуальных.
2. Кто то утверждает что виртуальный процессор может эмулироватся программно молл виртуальный процессор можно сравнить с операционной системой. Поток по отношению к нему выступает как процесс, подобно тому, как сам виртуальный процессор является процессом с точки зрения операционной системы.
3. Еще говорят что при создании виртуальной машины можно для нее выделять виртуальные процессоры

**ТАК ЧТО ТАКОЕ ВИРТУАЛЬНЫЙ ПРОЦЕССОР**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88065/discussion-on-question-by-zeliboba----).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не термин, а обычное словосочетание. Виртуальный процессор - это нечто, что выглядит как работоспособный процессор, но процессором не является. Точное значение зависит от контекста.

1. Так, когда-то давно никто не слышал про многоядерные процессоры, а когда было нужно - ставили несколько процессоров. И когда многоядерные процессоры появились - то в целях обратной совместимости каждое ядро стало "представляться" операционной системе как отдельный процессор. То есть у вас на материнке стоит один проц - а ОС пишет, что их два. Никакого второго процессора реально не существует, он - виртуальный. Точнее, оба ядра называют виртуальными процессорами, потому что они одинаковые.
2. Существуют эмуляторы процессоров. Например, вы можете скачать эмулятор NES и поиграть на нем в старые игры. Эти игры написаны для процессора Ricoh 2A03, но играть в них вы будете на процессоре семейства Intel. Однако большинство игр подмены не заметят, поскольку эмулятор реализует все нужные инструкции. В этом смысле эмулятор NES содержит в себе виртуальный процессор.
3. Внутри виртуальной машины работает реальная ОС, называемая "гостевой". Эта ОС, точно так же, как и при работе вне виртуальной машины, пытается работать с "железом". Но у виртуальной машины все "железо" - виртуальное (за редкими исключениями): если вы, к примеру, зайдёте в Диспетчер устройств на виртуалке с виндой - вы не увидите ничего похожего на реальные устройства. Процессоры у виртуальной машины - тоже виртуальные.